# Почему цикл останавливается при i =1?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table width=90% border=2>
    <tr>
      <td id="0">1</td>
      <td id="2">2</td>
      <td id="3">3</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <p>yo yo yoy</p>
  <script language="javascript">
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    alert(i);
    if(document.getElementById(String(i)).innerHTML == "2") {
      document.getElementById(String(i)).innerHTML = "what";
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Вылетает эксепшн

Comment: В консоль залоггировало.

Comment: Почему документ закрывается через </head>?

Comment: @Duoxx по той же причине, что `<tr>` закрывается `</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что элемента с `id="1"` нет, `document.getElementById("1")` возвращает `null`, a `null.innerHTML` приводит к ошибке и прерыванию исполнения кода.

```
if(document.getElementById(String(i)) != null &&
  document.getElementById(String(i)).innerHTML == "2") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Более того, идентификаторы должны начинаться с буквы. (в HTML5 можно и цифры, но вот в css #1 {} не прокатит).

Comment: @lampa, _но вот в css #1 {} не прокатит_, а вот так _#\31_ [прокатит](https://jsfiddle.net/yt6qe3d5/) :-D

Comment: @lampa легко, через `[id="1"]`  https://jsfiddle.net/gdzc96v4/